# The Data Contains Faulty Readings with certain format

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-processing

I have a pandas df, where one of my columns have faulty values. I want to clean these values

The Faulty Values are negative and end with <, example '-2.44<'.
How do I fix this without affecting other columns? My index is Date-Time

I have tried to convert the column to numeric data.

```
df.values = pd.to_numeric(df.values, errors='coerce')
```

There are no error messages. But, I'd like to replace them with removing '<'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) for remove `<` from right side:

```
df.values = pd.to_numeric(df.values.str.rstrip('<'), errors='coerce')
```

Or more general is used [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) - possible add more values:

```
df.values = pd.to_numeric(df.values.str.strip('<>'), errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Does the '<>' remove either '<' or '>' or both ?

Comment: @SakibShahriar - It remove one or second or both form left or right side